# jQuery check detection, hiding previous (jsFiddle enclosed)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove text fields with checkboxes as shown in the jsFiddle. However, as you can see, one of the boxes is checked but its corresponding text field exists. Can someone help me edit this to get this to hide the corresponding text fields for already checked items on load?

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/masedesign/jdbmK/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BOOYAH http://jsfiddle.net/jdbmK/4/

Comment: Since when is two DOM lookups simpler than one? :P

Comment: I like your enthusiasm. Thank you all, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/NqKP9/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.check').each(function() {
        $(this).prev().toggle(!$(this).is(':checked'));
    });
    $('.check').click(function() {
        $(this).prev().toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go. Since you already hit the dom for all .check, you can just filter that result into ones that are currently `:checked` status, and hide the previous element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.check').click(function() {
        $(this).prev().toggle();
    }).filter(':checked').each(function(){
        $(this).prev().hide();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/robert/F2vkq/

Answer (score 0):

You're checking the box with the `checked` attribute, but you have no code that looks for checkboxes that have been set this way.

```
$('.check').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        $(this).prev('.date').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jdbmK/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.check').click(function() {
        $(this).prev().toggle();
    });
    // toggle already checked boxes
    $(':checked').each(function() {
        $(this).prev().toggle();
    })
});
```

Optimized version: http://jsfiddle.net/jdbmK/6/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function toggle() {
        $(this).prev().toggle();
    }
    $('.check').click(toggle);
    // toggle already checked boxes
    $(':checked').each(toggle);                
});
```